# C# Reflection Assignment

Tags: c#, reflection

so I need some help with this. I tried searching SOF, but I had no luck.

Using reflection, I need to test .NET String class. I need to show class name, interfaces that, this class implements, the assembly where this class is found, namespace of this class, type that inherits, and basic informations. Is this class abstract, generic, sealed etc. I had been learning this for 20 days, now, and I had no luck, so I was learning attributes, reflection, and assemblies, and metadata assemblies, EDIT: My question is: How to write this properly, I tried like 1000x, and nothing, always some mistakes, always errors, I do not know how to start..

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: "I need to test .NET String class" - do you mean `System.String`? or do you mean "I have a type name, as a string, and I want to reflect on the actual type"?

Comment: @MarcGravell yes man, System.String from .NET

Comment: @ravenousHydra well... those things on System.String aren't going to change (much)... I can tell you *right now* that it isn't abstract, which interfaces it implements, etc...? I'm ... unclear.

Comment: @MarcGravell So I didn't wrote this assignment, I just found it.. It's like same question from the author of assignment.. Well, I don't need change, I just need to display that information in console

Comment: @ravenousHydra this sounds a lot like homework... frankly, simply googling "reflection in .NET" would have got you about 90% of the way here...

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TellMeAboutType(typeof(string));
    }
    static void TellMeAboutType(Type type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + type.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Namespace: " + type.Namespace);
        Console.WriteLine("Assembly: " + type.Assembly.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("AQN: " + type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract: " + type.IsAbstract);
        Console.WriteLine("Generic: " + type.IsGenericType);
        Console.WriteLine("Sealed: " + type.IsSealed);
        Console.WriteLine("Base Type: " + type.BaseType.FullName);
        foreach(var iType in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Implements: " + iType.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Implements: {0}", string.Join(", ", type.GetInterfaces().Select(i => i.Name)));`

Answer (score 1):

I know Marc already answered, but I wanted to answer the short version of the question "How to start with reflection?"

Basically, you need a reference to the type. For that there are two methods:
1. In case you **know the type** (or it is a generic e.g. `<T>`): `typeof(MyType)` or `typeof(T)`.
2. In case you **have an object** instance, then you need to get the type first, which is also simple: `myObject.GetType()`

In both cases, then you just use the properties of the `Type` object you got, like Marc shown.

Comment: I know that, but, I am really trying, this is the hardest lesson for me, I know there are 3 ways to approach this, and I really tried every single way, with no luck... I know it's bad for me that Mr.Marc answered my result, and yes it's homework, but I was so pissed off, I am trying 20 days for this but nothing, I done it first time like Mr.Marc and I thought it's too simple it must be harder. So I complicated it, and I had freaked out.. Thanks for replies!